# How to update loggers in all managed servers at a time for tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

We have different managed servers in single environment. Now, I need to update all managed servers at a time when my request goes to one particular server. I should have a file in local with all IP's. Then when I hit one server rest three servers should also reflect the logs.

Comment: What do you mean by updating all the server's log files ?. and for what reason ? please provide more info.

Comment: When my request goes to one server, then logs will be generated for that server only as per current scenario. Now, suppose I have four managed servers in one application then, logs which I am getting on only one server now should be reflected in other three servers as well. so that I can check logs on all servers for single request.